# Ajax.ActionLink generated markup lacks onclick attribute

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I've got problem with generating ajax anchors. I'm using simple 
`Ajax.ActionLink("test", "Test", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId="test", HttpMethod="GET" })` and the generated markup is: 
`<a data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="GET" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#test" href="/Home/Test">test</a>`
which, obviously lacks the `onclick="Sys.Mvc.AsyncHyperlink.handleClick(...)"` attribute.

Anyone faced similar problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you use unobtrusive javascript, which does not require the onclick handler.

Unobtrusive javascript is enabled by default in asp.net mvc 3.

The link should work though.

Comment: Yeah, I just found it out too - and I haven't got jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js included. Thanks anyway!